# Движение растровой картинки по трассе в любую сторону при скролле

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

У меня есть растровая иконка автомобиля:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500"
     viewBox="0 0 672.474 933.78125">
  
<image id="car" transform="scale(2)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLbds.png" y="25" x="0"   width="50px" height="50px"/>
</svg>
```

И нарисованная в векторном редакторе трасса, вдоль которой должна двигаться иконка:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500"
     viewBox="0 0 672.474 933.78125">
<g transform="translate(-54.340447,-64.21875)" id="layer1">
   <path  fill="none" stroke="#914343" stroke-width="4"   id="path1" d="m 60.609153,64.432994 c 0,0 -34.345187,72.730986 64.649767,101.015256 98.99494,28.28427 321.2285,-62.62946 321.2285,-62.62946 0,0 131.31984,-52.527932 181.82746,16.16244 50.50763,68.69037 82.04198,196.41856 44.44671,284.86302 -30.25843,71.18422 -74.75128,129.29952 -189.90867,133.34013 -115.15739,4.04061 -72.73099,-153.54318 -72.73099,-153.54318 0,0 42.42641,-129.29953 135.36044,-119.198 92.93404,10.10152 -14.14213,-129.29953 -141.42135,-94.95434 -127.27922,34.34518 -183.84777,80.8122 -206.07112,121.2183 -22.22336,40.40611 -42.06243,226.23742 -26.26397,305.06607 8.77013,43.75982 58.20627,196.1403 171.72594,270.72088 73.8225,48.50019 181.82745,2.02031 181.82745,2.02031 0,0 94.95434,-12.12183 78.7919,-155.56349 -16.16244,-143.44166 -111.68403,-138.77778 -139.9683,-138.77778 -28.28427,0 83.39976,-156.18677 83.39976,-156.18677 0,0 127.27922,-189.90867 107.07617,16.16245 C 634.3758,640.21994 864.69058,888.71747 591.94939,941.2454 319.2082,993.77334 -16.162441,539.20469 153.54319,997.81395"/>
 </g>  
</svg>
```

Как заставить иконку автомобиля двигаться вдоль трассы при скролле?

Answer (score 5):

Растровую иконку автомобиля и `path` трассы размещаем в одном файле SVG.

Делается это для того, чтобы свести к минимуму усилия по позиционированию.

Анимацию движения вдоль трассы при скроллинге осуществляет JS.

Пояснения в комментариях кода:

```js
function positionCar()
{
  var  scrollY = window.scrollY  || window.pageYOffset ;
  var  maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var  path = document.getElementById("path1");
  // Рассчится расстояние по траектории, на которой машина должна быть на текущий момент прокрутки
  var  pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  var  dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
  var  pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
  // Рассчитайте положение немного впереди автомобиля (или позади, если мы в конце), чтобы мы могли рассчитать угол наклона автомобиля
  if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
    var  posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
    var  angle = Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
  } else {
    var  posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
    var  angle = Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
  }
  // Позиционирование автомобиля на «pos», повернутом на «angle»
  var  car = document.getElementById("car");
  car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ") rotate(" + rad2deg(angle) + ")");
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
}

// Передвигать автомобиль, когда есть событие прокрутки
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionCar);

// Начальная позиция автомобиля
positionCar();
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 9000px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
} 

#path1 {
fill:none;
stroke:#9EA5CD;
stroke-width:55;
stroke-linecap:butt;
stroke-linejoin:miter;
stroke-opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500"
     viewBox="0 0 672.474 933.78125">
  <g transform="translate(-54.340447,-64.21875)" id="layer1">
   <path     id="path1" d="m 60.609153,64.432994 c 0,0 -34.345187,72.730986 64.649767,101.015256 98.99494,28.28427 321.2285,-62.62946 321.2285,-62.62946 0,0 131.31984,-52.527932 181.82746,16.16244 50.50763,68.69037 82.04198,196.41856 44.44671,284.86302 -30.25843,71.18422 -74.75128,129.29952 -189.90867,133.34013 -115.15739,4.04061 -72.73099,-153.54318 -72.73099,-153.54318 0,0 42.42641,-129.29953 135.36044,-119.198 92.93404,10.10152 -14.14213,-129.29953 -141.42135,-94.95434 -127.27922,34.34518 -183.84777,80.8122 -206.07112,121.2183 -22.22336,40.40611 -42.06243,226.23742 -26.26397,305.06607 8.77013,43.75982 58.20627,196.1403 171.72594,270.72088 73.8225,48.50019 181.82745,2.02031 181.82745,2.02031 0,0 94.95434,-12.12183 78.7919,-155.56349 -16.16244,-143.44166 -111.68403,-138.77778 -139.9683,-138.77778 -28.28427,0 83.39976,-156.18677 83.39976,-156.18677 0,0 127.27922,-189.90867 107.07617,16.16245 C 634.3758,640.21994 864.69058,888.71747 591.94939,941.2454 319.2082,993.77334 -16.162441,539.20469 153.54319,997.81395"/>

    <image id="car"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLbds.png" y="-25" x="0"   width="50px" height="50px"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```